MongoDB starting then crashing
I was recently forced to remove and reinstall MongoDB on my web server, which is a VM running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Before I erased all of the previous MongoDB files, I copied the data directory /var/lib/mongodb to a backup directory, /var/lib/mongodb_backup_force. When I first redownloaded MongoDB, everything started and ran fine. However, upon copying the data files from the backup directory back to /var/lib/mongodb, restarting, and running sudo systemctl status mongod, I get the following errors:
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-12-24 20:51:26 EST; 12min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 29193 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 29193 (code=exited, status=14)

Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu mongod[29193]: {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-25T01:51:26.863Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":7484500, "ctx":"-","msg":"Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding \"processManagement.fork\" to false"}
Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I've tried running the following commands to change permissions:
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb, sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock, sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/*, and I've tried deleting the file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock. But to no avail.
When I consult the logs, I see An incomplete repair has been detected! This is likely because a repair operation unexpectedly failed before completing. MongoDB will not start up again without --repair. However, running mongod --repair fails with: Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this and get MongoDB running again.
Here is my /etc/mongod.conf file:
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:


Did you use the same version of MongoDB? Did you stop mongod before you made copy of the files?
